# Append multiple csv from directory to single dataframe and assign unique ID based on individual csv filenames

Tags: r

I would like regularly import 100s of csv files from a directory, assign a unique ID to each file based on the individual file names, and then append the files to a single data frame.  As new files are uploaded to the directory, I would like the ability to append the new files to the dataframe.
I have:

I found several options to efficiently append all files from a directory, but I have not found a way to attach a unique id that corresponds to the file name of each file.

To import and append files from a directory I used:

```
library(data.table)
setwd("C:/data")
Filelist <- list.files()
appenddata = rbindlist(lapply( filelist, fread,  header=TRUE ))
```

To create a unique ID I use:

```
Appenddata$id = substr(filelist, 1, 20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past I've just rep() the filename as a column and looped over the csv files like this:

```
df <- data.frame()
for(file in files){
  new_df <- read.csv(file)
  new_df$id <- rep(file, nrow(new_df))
  df <- rbind(df, new_df)
}
```

If you need better performance. You might look at reading the dataframes into a list, doing creating your id file via lapply and then rbinding them all at once.